# customize enumerate

Tags: enumerate

I want to make a list like below:

```
1-10. as above list
11. bla bla
12. bla bla
...
```

I tried to make the first line as normal text, and make a `enumerate` starts at 10, but it does not work, because the first line has different indent and font and etc. (I am using Springer LNCS format).

How could I make a list like above?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that the counter `enumi` is sometimes replaced by other packages, not to mention nesting levels.  The numbers in enumerate are right justified, so the left edge is a moving target.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\newlength{\tempdima}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item[]\hspace{-\leftmargin}1-10.  as above list (left aligned to edge of text area)
\settowidth{\tempdima}{11.}%
\item[]\hspace{-\itemsep}\hspace{-\tempdima}1-10.  as above list (left aligned to 11.)
\item[1-10.] as above list (right aligned to other numbers)
\setcounter{enumi}{10}%
\item bla bla
\item bla lba
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]